# Server role config with ContentManagement,Processing,Reporting not working

Tags: configuration

We wanted to setup a server as ContentManagement,Processing and Reporting instance. As we can combine roles, we changed the config accordingly.

```
<add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement,Processing,Reporting" />
```

We immediatly got errors and noticed that we hadn't done the content management setup as described [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/content-management/index.html). So we set the serviceUrl's and got rid of the errors. Looked weird to send all requests for processing and reporting to ourselves but still.. let's try to follow the guide.

But.. our server went berzerk.. CPU peaking, no responses anymore.

We tried to set the server (back) into the "Standalone" role, and he worked fine. So, something seems wrong with the config role setup?

Using Sitecore 9.0-update1. Trying to setup a CM (incl reporting & processing) + CD...

Comment: Any idea if this issue is resolved for Sitecore 9.1?

Comment: I would assume it is, but haven't been able to test that yet

Comment: I was checking with Sitecore 9.1 and got the same errors when role was defined as above

Comment: @PankajTiwari - Did you get the errors for Sitecore 9.1 Initial Release?

Comment: @VarunShringarpure, yes we had similar errors on Sitecore 9.1 initial release but removing content management from role solved the issue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We called upon Sitecore Support and they told us this was a "bug". It will be documented but until that is done, you can follow this guide:

1. *App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.xDB\Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Client.config*:
   set role:require on sitecore element to "ContentManagement AND !Reporting"

   `<sitecore role:require="ContentManagement AND !Reporting">`
2. *App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.xDB\Sitecore.Xdb.Remote.Server.config*: set role:require on reporting element to "Reporting AND !ContentManagement"

   `<reporting role:require="Reporting AND !ContentManagement">`
3. *App_Config\Sitecore\PathAnalyzer\Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.RemoteClient.config*: set role:require on sitecore element to "ContentManagement AND !Reporting"

   `<sitecore role:require="ContentManagement AND !Reporting">`
4. *App_Config\Sitecore\PathAnalyzer\Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Services.RemoteServer.config*: set role:require on sitecore element to "Reporting AND !ContentManagement"

   `<sitecore role:require="Reporting AND !ContentManagement">`
5. *App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Operations.Xdb.ReferenceData\Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.Xdb.ReferenceData.config*: set role:require on sitecore element to "(Processing or Reporting) AND !ContentManagement"

   `<sitecore role:require="(Processing or Reporting) AND !ContentManagement">`
6. *App_Config\Sitecore\Marketing.Operations.Xdb.ReferenceData\Sitecore.Marketing.Operations.Xdb.ReferenceData.config*: 
   Set role:require on sitecore element to "(Processing or Reporting) AND !ContentManagement"

   `<sitecore role:require="(Processing or Reporting) AND !ContentManagement">`

When doing this, there is no more need to set serviceUrl and such as the remoting for reporting and processing server is turned off as it should.

Comment: I guess at the end of the day.. what's the difference between "Standalone" and "CM/Process/Reporting"?  At that point, you're just excluding CD, which... to be fair, generally you want to deliver elements of your site.  My assumption is the Sitecore probably expected people to just use "Standalone" for that configuration then trying to call out each role.

Comment: We made that assumption as well, but as Support didn't tell us to just use Standalone we tried this. Will be checking the differences between Standalone and our combi to see if there is any benefit in doing this.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to have solved the issue. Is there a public reference number for the Sitecore bug?

Comment: There are 3: 205757, 203749, 205439

Comment: @PeteNavarra I thought the same however was slightly concerned that this may impact the inter-role communication eg. Publish / Indexing events etc.

Gatogordo have you noticed anything particular around the processing remotes/clients, they haven't been called out and I would think that the issue may be similar?

Comment: My thoughts: https://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2018/03/sitecore9-configuration-roles-content-management.html   I wouldn't expect issues with either setups, but to be honest in the end we turned back to standalone..

Comment: @Gatogordo thanks for that post. It's also now documented that to run the roles in your planned configuration you should set it to ContentManagement only and ensure that the reporting and processing connection strings are present - although that seems a bit of a hack. For reference we have set the role to ContentMangagement and applied the changes Sitecore outlined above. So far its working.

Comment: "Standalone" won't work if you're using the instance as a remote reporting instance i.E. you have a ContentManagement only instance connecting to reporting.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this issue has now been resolved in Sitecore 9 Update 2: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/90/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%2090%20Update2/Release%20Notes

"The Experience Analytics and Path Analyzer applications fail to start on a Sitecore instance that is configured with the following role combination: Content Management, Processing, and Reporting ."

Comment: Not completely. On 9 Update-2 You will still have to patch Sitecore.Marketing.Taxonomy.Xdb.ReferenceData.config
Sitecore.Marketing.Operations.Xdb.ReferenceData.config