# Sitecore 9.0.1 Custom ARM template for XP1 with combined roles

Tags: azure, paas, arm-template

I want to create an ARM template to setup 9.0.1 PaaS with the following configuration:

- 1 appservice with CM, Reporting and Processing
- 1 appservice with CD
- xDB fully scaled

I'm trying to determine how to go about doing this. Looking at https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates as a starting point, I believe my options are either:

- Deploy two XP0's and xDB. Use server roles to gate responsibility.
- Start with the XP1 template and modify the nested json files to remove the additional infrastructure to combine roles.

Are there other options that I haven't explored? What would be the recommended way for setting this up?

Comment: Don’t really know, but removing infrastructure sounds easier than adding it to existing deployments. I mean, one would end up with extra infraestructure instead of missing things. Granted it can backfire but the odds of it seem much less given one starts with a fully working comprehensive environment.

Comment: You might want your first appservice to be set as standalone.. check https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/9961/237 if you need want to have those roles combined

Comment: @Gatogordo good to know. I'm going to try to use the settings in that SSE link but if that doesn't work, I'll switch to standalone - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would start from the XP1 template.

Remove the Reporting and Processing from the infrastructure and application templates.

Finally, add the roles reporting and processing to CM. For this you will need to start from the cm-package provided by sitecore and adapt the web.config file.
    
         Specify the roles that you want this server to perform. A server can perform one or more roles. Enter the roles in a comma separated list. The supported roles are:

```
     ContentDelivery
     ContentManagement
     Processing
     Reporting
     Standalone

Default value: Standalone
-->
<add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement, Processing, Reporting"/>
```

Good luck!

Comment: my goal was to avoid modifying the WDPs and unfortunately I couldn't determine a way to use the XP1 template to accommodate this without doing so. I ended up deploying a full XP1 and deleting the processing and reporting appservices and setting the roles as you mentioned above