# Using Server Roles for Sitecore 9 CM Server

Tags: deployment, server-role

I want to have a single cm server with 2 cd servers. I installed the cm server using the normal install (xp0) and on the other servers I used xp1 cd. The servers seems to be coordinating with each other fine. I set the role of the cm server to be the following:

`<add key="role:define" value="ContentManagement,Processing,Reporting" />`

Unfortunately while doing this, I get the following error while trying to browse to a custom item:
[image: Error]

I tried switching the server role to `Standalone` and that seems to work however that doesn't seem like the right role to be using. Just using the `ContentManagement` role alone also seems to have fixed this issue but doesn't seem right either since I do want analytic data to be processed. Is there a way to get around needing 2 additional servers for the `Processing` and `Reporting` roles?

Answer (score 1):

If you are NOT separating the Processing and Reporting roles from the Content Management Server, set the CM Server to **Standalone**.

There is a known configuration issue with using the Processing and Reporting roles together.

Using the "Standalone" role on the CM will still allow you to use the CD roles appropriately.

This is also listed as a question already [Server role config with ContentManagement,Processing,Reporting not working](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/server-role-config-with-contentmanagement-processing-reporting-not-working)