# Installing CM and CD - binding

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework, installation, content-management

I am new to sitecore so my understanding of the solution is very limited. 
Anyway i am currently trying to install the following Sitecore XP1 topology :

- CD1 and CD2 (content delivery servers)
- CM1 (content management, processing, reporting, ...)
- SOLR server and SQL server (already installed)

I am using a Powershell scripts to install CM and CD roles : 
(ex for the cm role on the CM server)

```
Import-Module SitecoreFundamentals
Import-Module SitecoreInstallFramework

#define parameters 
$FilesRoot = "C:\Sitecore\installer"
$prefix = "pprd_sc"
$sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix"+"_cm01"

#################################
#       deploy CM instance 
#################################
$cmParams = 
@{
    Path = "$FilesRoot\config\sitecore-XP1-cm.json"     
    Package = "$FilesRoot\sources\Sitecore 9.0.1 rev. 171219 (OnPrem)_cm.scwdp.zip"
    LicenseFile = "$FilesRoot\license.xml"    
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix
    SSLCert = "*.mydomain.com"
    XConnectCert = "*.mydomain.com"
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName
    SitecoreAdminPassword = ""
    SqlAdminUser = "sa"
    SqlAdminPassword = ""
    SqlCoreUser = "sql_core_user"
    SqlCorePassword = ""
    SqlMasterUser = "sql_master_user"
    SqlMasterPassword = ""
    SqlWebUser = "sql_web_user"
    SqlWebPassword = ""
    SqlReportingUser = "sql_reporting_user"
    SqlReportingPassword = ""
    SqlReferenceDataUser = "sql_reference_data_user"
    SqlReferenceDataPassword = ""
    SqlFormsUser = "sql_forms_user"
    SqlFormsPassword = ""
    SqlExmMasterUser = "sql_exm_master_user"
    SqlExmMasterPassword = ""
    SqlMessagingUser = "sql_messaging_user"
    SqlMessagingPassword = ""
    SqlServer = "SQLSCOREPP"
    SolrUrl = "https://slrscorepp.mydomain.com:8984/solr"
    XConnectReferenceDataService="https://cmscorepp.mydomain.com"
    MarketingAutomationOperationsService="https://cmscorepp.mydomain.com"
    MarketingAutomationReportingService="https://cmscorepp.mydomain.com"
} 
Install-SitecoreConfiguration @cmParams -Verbose
```

and other scripts that look like this one for the roles:

- Collection
- CollectionSearch
- Referencedata
- MarketingAutomation
- MarketingAutomationReporting
- Reporting
- Processing
- and the CM

2 problems:

if my sitename does not contain the domain name .mydomain.com https cannot work and the install fails. How can I specify different sitename and url to use during the install.

this install does not create a binding "xconnect.mydomain.com" that the Content Delivery should use. Does a manually added binding works? How does the link between CD and CM works?

Comment: Make sure you are asking a single question. If you have multiple questions, you should create multiple questions.

Comment: In my experience, it's best to set up the CM server with the standalone role. There is an existing question on SSE that points that out as the simplest method for achieving what you're after. Doesn't solve all of your problems, but should help.

Comment: Ok I just found the question you are mentionning. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/server-role-config-with-contentmanagement-processing-reporting-not-working 
In the end I did the following steps on the CM : 
1. Create the xconnect cert with xconnect-createcert.json you can find in the xp0 install
2. installed xconnect-xp0
3. installed sitecore-xp0
4. edit my bindings

Seems to work so far. Standaone is the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. During the install, You can have the siteName as cms.mydomain.com , then after the install finishes you can change the IIS bindings and update sitecore config (under `<sites>` node)  to use any other domain
2. CM and CD don't talk to each other directly and don't know about each others URLs, But they use shared resources instead, Such as EventQueue table in Web database which is shared between CM and CD, Also xConnect is shared between CM and CD and you can find the xConnect URL in ConnectionStrings.config file for both CM and CD.
3. For CD instances, I usually copy the entire website root from CMS server and update `role:define` inside web.config file to be `ContentDelivery`, You may need to clean up the ConnectionStrings.config file on CD and remove any connection that CD does not use.
4. Make sure that `<setting name="InstanceName" value=""/>` for each CM,CD site is unique, By default it will take the server name + IIS website name

Comment: Ok I just found a question on SSE: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/9961/server-role-config-with-contentmanagement-processing-reporting-not-working In the end I did the following steps on the CM : 1. Create the xconnect cert with xconnect-createcert.json you can find in the xp0 install 2. installed xconnect-xp0 3. installed sitecore-xp0 4. edit my bindings Seems to work so far. Standaone is the way.